# Behaviour of FreeQ with Except

Tags: pattern-matching, expression-test

I tried to test if a list has non-numeric elements using `FreeQ` as follows:

```
FreeQ[{"sa", "sa", {"sa", "sa"}, x}, Except[_?NumericQ], {-1}]
```

which gives `False` and apparently contradicts what I expect as the list doesn't contain any numeric element.

How can this behavior of `FreeQ` be explained?

---

**Edit**

I realised the mistake I made in the previous example.

However, for the case below

```
{FreeQ[{1, 2, 2, 1}, Except[_?NumericQ], {-1}], FreeQ[{1, 2, 2, 1}, _?NumericQ, {-1}]}
```

I would expect `{True,False}` but it gives `{False,False}`.

Is there something I'm still missing?

Comment: `Heads->False`...

Comment: Thanks @ciao. Does that mean Mathematica actually tests `Integer[1]` rather than `1`?

Comment: No, try putting a `Print` or `Sow` in the test - you'll see without `Heads->False`, the list head itself is also passed to test...

Comment: Now I get it. Thanks so much, @ciao!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your code, you are asking: "Keep checking until you find an instance of this pattern. If that instance exists, return false. Return true otherwise." Your pattern is "not a number". Hence, `FreeQ` checks the first item, finds it is not a number, returns false. Use the following code to track which elements are being tested. I removed the offending `Except` call to avoid the double negation.

```
FreeQ[{"sa", "sa", {"sa", "sa"}, 
  x}, _?((Print[#]; NumericQ[#]) &), {-1}, Heads -> False]
```

Comment: `Heads -> False` saved me. I didn't notice this option. Also the `Print` helps locating the issue.

Answer (score 4):

You have simply inverted the pattern you should have used, which is `_?NumericQ`. You are asking, "Is my list free of things that ***are not*** numerics?", when you really meant to ask is, "Is my list free of that ***are*** numerics?"

Your error is analogous to the common beginner error in procedural languages of writing

```
i = 1; While[i > 5, ++i]; i
```

when the coder really meant to write

```
i = 1; While[i < 5, ++i]; i
```

and wondering why the result is 1 and not 5,